# html table, изменение элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Можно ли изменять элементы таблицы html как массив, примерно так?

```
document.getElementById('tab')[i][j]='текст'
```

Comment: html тег `table` при создании DOM транслируется в объект [HTMLTableElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement), у него есть свойство `rows` --  HTMLCollection (коллекция создается на основе тегов tr). у HTMLCollection есть индексатор, который позволяет получить доступ к элементу по его индексу. такой же синтаксис используется в массивах. если надо получить первый `tr` в table, то пишем так `document.getElementById('tab').rows[0]`. получим [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement), у которого есть свойство `cells`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но не так. И это не совсем массив.
Он не прямоугольный, надо считать строку и ячейку *в ней*.

```js
document.querySelector("table").rows[3].cells[1].textContent = ".";
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid;
  line-height: 2em;
}

td {
  width: 2em;
  vertical-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3</tr>
  <tr><td>4<td>5<td>6</tr>
  <tr><td>7<td>8<td>9</tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2>0<td>*</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А где можно почитать про это?

Comment: @Юрий, про что?

Comment: про все атрибуты тэгов html. Нигде, где написано про table, я не нашел таких атрибутов, как rows

Comment: @Юрий, это свойства, а не атрибуты.